# Troubles Switching From Natbib to Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I'm currently trying to switch from natbib to biblatex - following the suggestions given in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex) answer - but am having some problems.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}


\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{/Users/James/Documents/library.bib}

\title{Figuring Out How to Get an APA Bibliography}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

I'm trying to get an APA-style bibliography by switching from Natbib to Biblatex. The APA-style is used by \citet{Steinberger2019}, but also by \citet{Becker2012} and \citet{Beall2005}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

But this outputs:

[image]

The references are bold, which they shouldn't be, they're not formatted properly (i.e. with the year in parentheses), and there's no bibliography. Where have I gone wrong?

(I should mention that I use Mendeley to manage my references, and so my external bibliography file has to be a .bib file, since this is what Mendeley outputs)

Here are the error messages I got:

[image]

Comment: Two questions: (a) Did you run `biber`, and did you get any error messages? (b) Have you tried replacing `\bibliography` with `\addbibresource`?

Comment: Hi, (a) I have not run biber, do you mean I should just add \usepackage{biber} even though my bibliography file is in .bib format? (b) I get the same result if I use \addbibresource instead

Comment: With natbib you use the `bibtex` programme to generate the bibliography, with biblatex you use `biber` format the bibliography

Comment: There is a very common mistake here, like with latex bibtex means two things: the name of a programme, and the name for a way to format data. The input data for biblatex/biber is still in the bibtex dataformat for it is processed by the `biber` programme as it is vastly more powerful than `bibtex`

Comment: Hi, I'm still a rookie to latex! Could you spell out what I need to do to fix the above problem, please?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: The link Johannes posted is the go-to Q&A for configuring your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains why you need to run Biber (or BibTeX) in the first place.

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to resolve your issue? Can this be closed as a duplicate of the standard https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864?

Comment: Hi, yes it can be closed as a duplicate. Thanks!